# Youtube Python API LiveChatMessages insert ERROR_UNSPECIFIED

Tags: python, youtube

I'm working on writing a python script that utilizes the Youtube Live API. I can read messages using the `liveChatMessages().list()` method, but am getting a strange error about an invalid argument when I attempt to create a message with `liveChatMessages().insert()`.

The below is the source code responsible for sending messages:

```py
    def send_message(self, message):
        body = {
            'snippet': {
                'liveChatId': self.stream_id,
                'type': 'textMessageEvent',
                'textMessageDetails': {
                    'messageText': message
                }
            }
        }

        self.youtube.liveChatMessages().insert(part='snippet', body=body).execute()
```

The following is the errror that I'm getting

```
googleapiclient.errors.HttpError: <HttpError 400 when requesting https://youtube.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/liveChat/messages?part=snippet&alt=json returned "Request contains an invalid argument.". Details: "[{'domain': 'youtube.api.v3.LiveChatMessageInsertResponse.Error', 'reason': 'ERROR_UNSPECIFIED'}]">
```

I have been following the API documentation found at https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/live/docs/liveChatMessages/insert and https://developers.google.com/resources/api-libraries/documentation/youtube/v3/python/latest/youtube_v3.liveChatMessages.html#insert

Comment: can you try to change the content of your `body` variable  as is shown [here](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/live/docs/liveChatMessages/insert?apix=true)? - please, try it and let us know.

Comment: I'm not sure that I follow. When I'm on that page and I look to see the code example, I don't see any difference between the auto-generated body and the one that I have (other than substituting hardcoded strings for variables that are also strings)

Answer (score 0):

I've had this same problem with Dart instead of Python:

```
await youTubeApi!.liveChatMessages.insert(
    LiveChatMessage(
        snippet: LiveChatMessageSnippet(
            liveChatId: chatId,
            type: "textMessageEvent",
            textMessageDetails: LiveChatTextMessageDetails(messageText: message)))
```

Resulting in the "400 Request contains an invalid argument" error.

The solution was simple: I forgot to activate the YouTube channel of the account. **Check whether you can write into the chat manually.**